# Change the icon for php files in directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How can I change the file icon of my directory index? 
I want to change the icon of php files so whenever my directory is requested it should display my own icon. how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AddIcon](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) directive in your .htaccess

```
 AddIcon (IMG,http://example.com/image.png) .php
```

or for an image with relative path ,

```
 AddIcon (IMG,/image.png) .php
```